# Proper way to assign Varible in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

On Following Controller i am unable to Assign a variable called "Emails". I'm getting error on that variable. Please check [picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrTRP.png) [picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3sVN.png) for understand better. Whats the problem how can i solve this error?

```
//[HttpPost]
        [HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult EmailCampaignProcess(FormCollection collection)
        {
            var Emails;
            var userType = Request["userType"];
            var emailContent = Request["emailContent"];

            if (userType == "subscriber")
            {
                Emails = db.Users.Where(d => d.Subscriptions.Any(x => x.Status == true)).Select(u => u.Email).ToArray();
            }
            else if(userType == "unsubscriber")
            {
                Emails = db.Users.Where(d => d.Subscriptions.Any(x => x.Status == false)).Select(u => u.Email).ToArray();
            }
            else if (userType == "protentialClient")
            {
                Emails = db.Users.Where(d => d.Subscriptions.Any(x => x.Status == false)).Select(u => u.Email).ToArray();
            }


            foreach (string Email in Emails) {

                SendSimpleMessage(Email);

            }

            return HttpNotFound();

        }
```

Comment: Declare your Emails variable as a specific type, maybe `string[] Emails`. Just using `var` in this case will not work.

Comment: Your `var Emails;` needs to enable it to determine a type from the inference.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, I believe you have to declare the actual type of the variables you declare. Would changing it to

```
string[] Emails;
```

solve your problem?

Comment: https://expirebox.com/download/a14dca283c7ea54199e8ec655d5bd21b.html

Comment: first error solved now second one left

Answer (score 1):

At first, `var Emails;` caused this error:

> implicitly typed local variables must be initialized.

that means you can't define a variable using `var` without initializing the value because the `type of value` defines `type of variable`, so you can initialize it like:

```
string[] Emails = null;
```

or

```
var Emails = new string[] { };
```

After that, because have no else in your `if-else if` structure, you must initialize with a non-value data like the second one.

Comment: `= null` is superfluous since it is the default.

Answer (score 0):

While you can solve the problem you describe with Tim Leach's answer, you might run into a NullReference error later on when you loop through the emails. After all, you do not assign any emails if for whatever reason `userType` is something else than the three options you programmed for.

Therefore, you might consider

```
var Emails = new string[0];
```

Or simply include a test on `userType`, or a null-check before your foreach.

Also, consider following standard naming conventions, meaning that your variable should be `emails`, not `Emails`.

Finally, consider simplifying your repeating code by doing something like

```
var status = userType == "subscriber";
var emails = Emails = db.Users.Where(d => d.Subscriptions.Any(x => x.Status == status)).Select(u => u.Email).ToArray();
```

Now you don't need your separate declaration anymore, and you can remove three if-statements.

Answer (score 0):

Using `var` only works when you declare and assign a value to your variable and the type of the value can be inferred from the expression.

In this case the compiler has no way of knowing what value to assign to the Emails variable.

Judging from the code below the declaration where value is assigned to the variable, you should declare it as an array of strings as suggested by the other answers.

```
string[] Emails = null;
```